# pg_dump database with several schemas with PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I created a backup of a postgres database which contains the public and 3 more schemas like this:

```
pg_dump -a -d my_database -h localhost -U my_user -Fc > my_database.stage.2023.08.25.pgdump
```

When I want to restore the database locally I get a bunch of exceptions, like schema aaa does not exist or even relation public.auth_group does not exist etc. I would expect that I get the same database content as on the original system for local testing. I created an empty database for the restore.

How can I do a full backup of my database that consists of several schemas including all schemas with data, structure, sequences, keys etc.

Thanks and Regards
Matt

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postgresql+backup

Comment: "a bunch of exceptions" is not a very clear problem description.

Comment: `pg_dump -a` means that you only dump the data, not the structure. That's what `-a` does, what you asked for. You can import the result in any database, as long as the structure has been created. Or create a different dump: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Comment: The problem seems to be that schemas are not backed up. I do not know if the complete error messages would be helpful. I could paste them here but what for? I am looking for the possibility to backup a database including all schemas & data.I would also expect that they are created if not existing. I do not want to use dumpall as I do not want to backup the postgres and other databases. The link is not helpful as It is to general and does not cover the schema problem.

Comment: Thanks Frank, must have overlooked that. So by default all schemas are backed up then?

Comment: @Matt Yes, If you don't use the extra options, you get a complete dump, including the complete schema, all functions and all data. When you start using the options, it depends on you what the result will be.

Answer (score 0):

Without the -a option in the pg_dump command it is working as expected. As Frank already mentioned in a comment.